# MSBuild does not match Visual Studio when referencing an indirectly referenced DLL

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, dynamic-library

I apologize for asking this question, but I'm pretty sure the answer is "MSBuild is dumb, VS is smart".

An indirectly referenced DLL is a DLL that is referenced from a directly referenced DLL but not referenced in the project at all.

I have project A (web application) referencing project B (class library). Project B has a direct reference (meaning its actually used in the project) to DLL 1. DLL 1 has a reference to DLL 2.

When I build in visual studio, DLL 1 and DLL 2 are both copied to my local bin in project A (web application). When I build with MSBuild, DLL 2 is NOT copied to the local bin in project A.

Is there any way I can fix this, without using the lib method and having the DLL marked as copy to bin (as a file instead of as a reference), and then adding a scan for /bin/lib?